# How do I get Sass to work with Phalcon?

Tags: css, sass, phalcon

I'm trying to use Sass together with Phalcon, without success thus far. I've followed [Derek Banas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz3kElLbEHE) tutorial on Sass, but Sass still wont compile (I think).

This is my Sass "project" within my Phalcon project: [image]

You can see the files being loaded into my browser here: [image]

`index.scss` Is the file I'm trying to modify.

And at last my `index.scss` code:

```
@import "compass";
@import "partials/variables";
@import "partials/normalize";

*{
    background-color: $dark_orange !important;
}
```

When I just try plain CSS, it works fine. This is what I've tried:

```
@import "compass";
@import "partials/variables";
@import "partials/normalize";

*{
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

I'm also making use of bootstrap and [John Albin's normalize CSS](https://github.com/npmcomponent/JohnAlbin-normalize-scss).

I have no idea why it isn't working so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your browser loading `index.scss`? Shouldn't you be loading `index.css`? ie. the compiled file?

Comment: Just came here to say that, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was including `sass/index.scss` instead of `css/index.css`. It works now!